# executing a script automatically in flash builder

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

I did a simple animation with adobe flash catalyst with 4 states. and I want to make the transitions between states happen automatically (with a delay between each transition). O made it with a button but I don't know how to add a script that get executed automatically when the animation launches.

Comment: Show some code and/or post a SWF with what you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register for the effectEnd events and play next ones.

Depending on how you coded this so far and what you did in Catalyst it may look different, but check the help manual about playing effects and transitions on state change.